# VBA End A For Loop WHEN IF ELSE CONDITION IS NOT MET

Tags: excel, vba

I want to stop the code from running with a message prompt when the if condition is not met.

I have tried with an else before the  end if statement but that doesn't seem to work.

I will really appreciate your help with this. Thanks in advanvce.

The if condition is nested in a for loop. Below is the section I am referring to:

```
 For i = 2 To last_row
 For ii = 8 To 1999
 Sheets("Schedule View").Range("K3").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value

If Worksheets("Schedule View").Cells(ii, 25).Value = Worksheets("Schedule 
View").Range("J3").Value And Worksheets("Schedule View").Cells(ii, 3).Value = 
Worksheets("Schedule View").Range("K3").Value Then

With Worksheets("Schedule View")
.Range(.Cells(ii, 1), .Cells(ii, 25)).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
b = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Schedule View").Activate
End With

End If



 Next


 #Rest of code here

 Next i
```

...

Full code below please.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 
 Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim rr As Long

Dim ColumnLetter As String

Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A:A"), "?*")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

For i = 2 To last_row

For ii = 8 To 1999

Sheets("Schedule View").Range("K3").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value

'On Error Resume Next

If Worksheets("Schedule View").Cells(ii, 25).Value = Worksheets("Schedule 
View").Range("J3").Value And Worksheets("Schedule View").Cells(ii, 3).Value = 
Worksheets("Schedule View").Range("K3").Value Then

'On Error Resume Next

With Worksheets("Schedule View")
.Range(.Cells(ii, 1), .Cells(ii, 25)).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
b = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Schedule View").Activate
End With


End If


Next

Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate


r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
rr = r - 24

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A26", "Y" & r).Select
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A26", "Y" & r).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A26", "Y" & r).Delete


Application.CutCopyMode = False


 'Convert To Column Letter
  ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, rr).Address, "$")(1)


Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1", ColumnLetter & "25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


 On Error GoTo 0

 If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
 End If

 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMail.To = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
olMail.Subject = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
olMail.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
 olMail.Send

MsgBox ("Roster sent to " + sh.Range("A" & i).Value)


   Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you tried using `Exit For`?

Comment: *I want to stop the code from running* You mean to End all execution? Quit your first loop? Quit both loops? Clearly you need to use Else but maybe you are not using it properly and i think it's because you got 2 loops so you are quitting only the second one and not the first one.

Comment: You can use GoTo if the condition is not met so you can jump over the part of the code you want to skip

Answer (score 1):

The go to did the trick for me. Thanks AlexHhz . Updated code below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim rr As Long

Dim ColumnLetter As String

Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A:A"), "?*")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

For i = 2 To last_row

For ii = 8 To 1999



Sheets("Schedule View").Range("K3").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value

If Worksheets("Schedule View").Cells(ii, 25).Value = Worksheets("Schedule 
 View").Range("J3").Value And Worksheets("Schedule View").Cells(ii, 3).Value = 
 Worksheets("Schedule View").Range("K3").Value Then

 'On Error Resume Next



With Worksheets("Schedule View")
.Range(.Cells(ii, 1), .Cells(ii, 25)).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
b = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Schedule View").Activate
End With


End If


Next


Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

If Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A26").Value = "" Then GoTo Line100 Else GoTo Line54

 'GoTo Line31 Else GoTo Line100

 Line54:
 r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
 rr = r - 24

 Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A26", "Y" & r).Select
 Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A26", "Y" & r).Copy
 Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
 False, Transpose:=True

 Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A26", "Y" & r).Delete


Application.CutCopyMode = False


 'Convert To Column Letter
 ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, rr).Address, "$")(1)


Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1", ColumnLetter & 
"25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


 On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If
'On Error Resume Next



 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
 Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 olMail.To = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
 olMail.Subject = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
 olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
 olMail.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
 olMail.Send

 MsgBox ("Roster sent to " + sh.Range("A" & i).Value)


   
   Next i
   
   Line100:

  MsgBox ("Messages Sent")

End Sub
```